# Example of a vector set that is ω-independent but not minimal

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, independence

I'm stuck proving the statement below. The point is that minimality of a vector set implies $\omega$-independence (see definitions below), but the converse is not true in general. Both concepts are generalizations of linear independence of vectors. The statement below is an example in which $\omega$-independence does not imply minimality.

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space. Further, assume that $(e_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is an orthonormal basis for $\mathcal{H}$.

$\underline{To\space Show:}$

The set $\{e_1\} ∪ \{e_k + e_{k+1}: k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is $\omega$-independent, but not minimal.

$\underline{Definition:}$

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $(\varphi_i)_{i\in I} \subset X$. Then $(\varphi_i)_{i\in I}$ is

- $\underline{\omega-independent}$ if whenever $\sum_{i\in I}c_i\varphi_i$ is convergent and equal to zero for some $(c_i)_{i\in I} \subset \mathbb{K}$, then $c_i = 0 \space\space\forall i \in I$.
- $\underline{minimal}$ if $\varphi_j \notin \overline{span\{\varphi_i: i \neq j \}}\space\space \forall j \in I$.

My attempt at the proof looks like this, but I'm stuck:

$\underline{Proof:}$

First, we'll have to show that the set above is indeed $\omega$-independent. Afterwards, we'll show that it is not minimal.

Let $(c_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{K}$ such that

$$ c_1 e_1 + \sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}}c_{k+1} (e_k + e_{k+1}) = 0. $$

Since $(e_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is an ONB we can break this sum up, so this is equivalent to

$$ c_1 e_1 + \sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}}c_{k+1} e_k + \sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}}c_{k+1} e_{k+1} = 0. $$

$$ \iff \sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}}c_{k+1} e_k + \sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}}c_k e_k = 0. $$

$$ \iff \sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}}(c_k + c_{k+1}) e_k = 0. $$

$$ \implies c_k + c_{k+1} = 0 \space\space \forall k \in \mathbb{N}.$$

$$ \iff c_{k+1} = - c_k \space\space \forall k \in \mathbb{N}.$$

At this point I'm stuck: This means the $c_k$ **don't** have to be all zero, so I must have made a mistake somewhere. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if $c_1 = 0$ and $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}, c_k = -c_{k+1}$ then by a quick reccurence, all the $c_k$ are equal to $0$.

Comment: @Tryss sure, but $c_1$ doesn't have to be zero.

Comment: if $c_1 = c \neq 0$, then $c_k = (-1)^n c$, and there is a little problem with the definition of $\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}} c_{k+1}(e_k+e_{k+1})$ (it's not absolutely convergent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set $g_1 = e_1$ and $g_n = e_{n-1} + e_{n}$.

You have found out that if $\sum c_n g_n = 0$, then $c_k = -c_{k+1}$. Set $c= | c_k|$, then this implies that either $c = 0$ or that $\sum_k c_k g_k$ is not converging to $0$. Indeed, since $\sum_{k=1}^m c_k g_k = c_m e_{m}$ we have that $\|\sum_{k=1}^m c_k g_k\| = c$ for all $m$, i.e., no convergence to $0$ if $c\neq 0$. One problem is, that $(g_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is also minimal as far as I can see. Hence, I give a reference to a working example below.

You can have a look at Section 6 of [Christopher Heil's "A Basis Theory Primer"](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~heil/papers/bases.pdf) and, in particular, Theorem 6.2. and the following Example 6.4. It is shown that minimality implies $\omega$-independence, but $\omega$-independence does not imply minimality, just as you request.

The example of a sequence that is $\omega$-independent but not minimal is very similar to your approach. The example is based on the sequence $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$, with $f_1 = e_1$ and $f_n = e_1 + e_n/n$, where $(e_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is an ONB.

Comment: Thank you! I studied their example in detail and unfortunately their argument doesn't seem to be applicable in my case. I still haven't managed to solve my situation above. Still this primer is a great resource.

Comment: So, do you mean, you have not been able to show that the sequence from your example is not minimal? Because I believe it is minimal. Concerning your proof, does my argument not show the $\omega$-independence sufficiently well?

Comment: The second sentence in your second paragraph: "This implies that either $c_k = 0$ for all $k$ or that $\sum_k c_k f_k$ is not converging to 0". I don't see that. $c_1$ could have any arbitrary value, e.g. 5. Then all $c_k$ would simply alternate between 5 and -5 and the whole thing converges to 0. The example in the primer is a good one, it's clear how and why the argument works there.

Comment: I haven't even touched on the minimality part yet. Still stuck with the $\omega$-independence part :/. Thanks so much for your help so far!

Comment: Well, I could have done a better job writing it down. The claim in the second sentence is substantiated in the third sentence. In the situation you describe, you actually have no convergence. 

The argument is, that all partial sums in your example have the same distance to 0.

Comment: You're right, I just didn't see it. Thanks a lot!